# Getting Started: Mongo, angular, node js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, ubuntu

I've decided I need to take on some new challenges and decided I want to learn to build an app  using mongo db, node js, and angular. I'm not sure where to begin. Do I need an apache server? if not how do i set up a localhost dev server? Any words of wisdom.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is a server, which can do the web app serving, so you do not need Apache.

You will see the term MEAN stack sometimes, e.g. [here](http://www.manning.com/sholmes/), for MongoDB (db), Express (template engine for Node.js), AngularJS (frontend framework) and Node.js (server), all programmable in JavaScript.

I would recommend the [Webstorm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) for getting into that environment.

Comment: Does mongo run directly in node?

Comment: No, it is a separate set of programms written in C++, but it is queried not in SQL but JavaScript. Bindings to other languages e.g. Ruby exist, of course.

Comment: So I would need a separate server like ubuntu to run the Mongo DB?

Comment: You need some operating system like Linux/Ubuntu, Windows, FreeBSD, MacOS X. There you run the Mongo DB server process for the DB and the Node.js server process for the web serving. The JavaScript on your backend app (running within Node.js) will communicate via network sockets with your MongoDB instance. The JavaScript in your browser frontend will communicate via AJAX with the JavaScript in your Node.js backend. You can run Node.js and MongoDB instances on the same machine or on different machines, if they are connected a network.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using this boilerplate could help you to kick off your project and could help you better in structuring your node.js project.

https://github.com/linnovate/mean